# SAP BusinessObjects XI upgrade 4.0 to R2 Class not registered

Tags: .net, business-objects

As we are moving to BO XI 4.0 from BO XI R2, uninstalled BOXI R2 from DEV server (WIN2003 server, 32 bit) and installed new BO XI 4.0. After that when I open my web application I am getting below error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C0C99FA5-E1D3-494E-BE0C-73C19424F91C} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C0C99FA5-E1D3-494E-BE0C-73C19424F91C} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I tried to register the dll manually:

`regsvr32  "C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\ClientDoc.dll"`

Got below error:

> LoadLibrary ("C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\ClientDoc.dll")failed - Invalid access to memory location.

Request any help regarding this.

Note: In local machine (winxp), the webapp is working fine without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of the issue:  Conflict with usage of different versions of "cryptocme2.dll" by CA's (Computer Associates) Autosys and SAP Business Objects XI 4.0.

Location of CA's file:  C:\Program Files\CA\SC\ETPKI\lib\cryptocme2.dll [Additional Info: File Version: Not Available, Timestamp: 2/29/2012 9:43 PM, size 3,188 KB]
Location of SAP's file : D:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\cryptocme2.dll  [ Additional Info:  File Version 3.0.0.0 , TimeStamp: 2/25/2011 6:55 PM, size: 1704 KB]

Solution:

1. Renamed the dll C:\Program Files\CA\SC\ETPKI\lib\cryptocme2.dll to cryptocme2_ca.dll
2. Copied the  D:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\cryptocme2.dll to  C:\Program Files\CA\SC\ETPKI\lib\
3. Uninstalled the BO XI 4.0 SDK (thru Control Panel) as it was not properly installed before.
4. Restarted the Box.
5. Stopped IIS Admin Server.
6. Then Installed BO XI 4.0 RAS 32 bit Dot Net SDK to D:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects

Now webapp is working fine.